# What's the best practise for multi-modules maven project in multi svn branch

Tags: java, svn, maven-2, branch

**Background**

1. one trunk and one branch in a standard svn layout, `/trunk` and `/branches/prod`
2. about 20 modules in the maven project
3. when i want to compile trunk, just type `cd trunk; mvn clean package`. but it will compile each of modules. something similar when the production need to be build.
4. a center maven repo

**Problem**

1. if it's possible to compile the updated module only? actually i want to compile the modified source files only if possible. i know it's a simple thing by `ant` or `make`. however, `maven compile` always make it from scratch.
2. should pom.xml in trunk and prod keep the same artifactId and version? the same artifactId and version cannot work with maven:deploy because trunk and prod will overwrite each others deployed packages.

Comment: Check out version 2.4 of the maven compiler plugin, it has some huge performance gains for multi-module projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the mvn -am -pl option which will limit the operation to a given module.

```
+-- root (pom.xml)
     +-- client (pom.xml) dep: core
     +-- server (pom.xml) dep: client
     +-- core (pom.xml) 
     +-- cli (pom.xml) dep:core
```

If you do a

```
mvn -am -pl server LifeCycle
```

only the server module and the modules which are used by the server will be run through the appropriate lifecycle.

```
mvn -am -pl cli LifeCycle
```

Only the cli module and the core module in this case will be run throught the given lifecycle.

Comment: The **-am -pl <arg>** arguments is exactly what i want. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

mvn compile does not always build from scratch. It only compiles changed java files. Unless you run mvn clean compile. Then of course, all projects will be cleaned and then compiled from scratch.

You can always cd into the project you want to and compile that by itself.

**edit** Maven *does* always run all the phases up to the compile phase if you invoke mvn compile and there may be plugin executions there that are time consuming. But the actual compiling of java files is not done more than needed. run mvn compile twice and you will see the message "nothing to compile all classes are up to date"

Or is it "all *files* are up to date"..?

**edit - question nbr 2**
Why are you releasing from both trunk and prod if the artifacts generated from the two are not different versions? *Yes* they should have different versions. Unless you create an experimental branch that you might merge back into trunk and you never intend to release it on its' own. In that case the experimental branch does not need a version number of its own.